# Converting mobile application (not an ecommerce app) event data to be compatible with google Recommendation AI

Tags: google-cloud-platform, mobile-application, recommendation-engine, google-cloud-recommendation

Here I'm working with a mobile application that is not an eCommerce application. I have event data collected in my google cloud. I want to create a recommendation model from that event data using the Recommendation AI service in the google cloud platform. When we ingest data to Recommendation AI, it needs both product data and event data. How can I create product data from my event data? I'm new to Recommendation AI. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a starting point I think your safe bet is to start with the official documentation. It provides a guide on how to start using recomendations AI.

- [How To Guide](https://cloud.google.com/retail/recommendations-ai/docs/how-to), Its a list of guides that teach the many steps that are involve in the usage of recommendations AI, and cover many aspects of it.
- [Implementing Recommendations AI with google marketing](https://cloud.google.com/retail/recommendations-ai/docs/overview#quick-implementation)
- [Implementing Recommendations AI without google marketing](https://cloud.google.com/retail/recommendations-ai/docs/overview#implementing_without_google_marketing), Looking for your description of your problem I think this will teach you the think process behind the usage process of recommendations AI.
- [Movie Recommendation Tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/retail/recommendations-ai/docs/movie-rec-tutorial)
- [API Documentation](https://cloud.google.com/retail/recommendations-ai/docs/apis)
- [Python Client](https://github.com/googleapis/python-retail)

About the specific last question scenario, I think one approach should be to build pipeline for transferring user-events data to recommendations AI in real-time via [Pub/Sub](https://cloud.google.com/pubsub/docs/tutorials) consume it ( You can use data-flow for it or a custom app that consumes your Pub/Sub ) and then use recommendations AI client to create the product and to add it to your catalog individually.

Note aside, I found this small implementation on github which makes use of the python client that you will find it interesting. ie: [Recommendations AI Python Examples using Retail API](https://github.com/EricDLarson/RetailAI/tree/master/python)

Also, if you are looking for a more wide set of recommendations options that the current [supported ones](https://cloud.google.com/retail/recommendations-ai/docs/placements#model-types), I strongly recommended to contact google 1:1 [support](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub).

Comment: I went through the official documents before asking this question. In that Recommendation AI official documents, they focused on eCommerce scenarios. I have a mobile application which is not related to eCommerce. That's why I asked this question. I want to convert my application events to a format which can be put in recommendation AI.

Comment: Are you looking for the [Product Class](https://cloud.google.com/retail/recommendations-ai/docs/reference/rest/v2/projects.locations.catalogs.branches.products#resource:-product)  details?? So you can know what to send in your `Product.Create` request to start filling your products catalog in the recommendations AI. Also you can find details about catalog, [here](https://cloud.google.com/retail/recommendations-ai/docs/catalog?&_ga=2.224481241.-270930302.1637072022#catalog-levels). Note: only one catalog per Google Cloud project.

Comment: Yeah, In the official document they tell how to create a Product Classes for eCommerce products. But in our case there are no products. We have a subscription based iOS application which is related to Procreate / (https://apps.apple.com/app/apple-store/id425073498) iOS application. We want to recommend things to customer in order to their behavior. That's why we are going to use Recommendation AI. We have events like "view appeared", "tool tapped", "subscription tapped" with user parameters and event parameters. I need to convert such kind of events in order to compatible with Rec AI.

Comment: I see, on that case you should contact directly to google support for 1:1 communication about this. Here is the [link](https://cloud.google.com/support-hub),  there it should provide you with personalized assistance.